# Best way to get index of most extreme peak/valley from a consecutive group of events?

Tags: python

Let's say i have some data, and then i also have an array which corresponds to this data that shows if a point is detected as a peak or valley encoded in 1s and -1s. However the caveat is that any point could be above or below the threshold, so an array could look like `[0,0,1,1,-1,-1,0,0]` in this case i'd only want to keep the peak and valley from the most extreme value in the corresponding array. For example let's say my actual data look like `[0,0,5,10,-5,-10,0,0]`, i would want to transform my array into `[0,0,0,1,0,-1,0,0]`. I only want the most extreme peak or valley from a group of consecutive events.

Comment: Why is the `5` encoded as a `1` in the first place?

Comment: @PMende it is encoded as being above a threshold. How determine which points are candidates for peaks isn't really my question. My question is after i have selected the indexes for points which could be considered a peak, how can i only recognize the most extreme point from consecutive events.

Answer (score 0):

The following should produce your desired result:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import argrelmax, argrelmin

def locate_extrema(arr):
    arr = np.asarray(arr)
    min_idxs = argrelmin(arr)
    max_idxs = argrelmax(arr)
    result = np.zeros_like(arr)
    result[min_idxs] = -1
    result[max_idxs] = 1
    return result
```

Using your example: `locate_extrema([0,0,5,10,-5,-10,0,0])`

Output:

```
array([ 0,  0,  0,  1,  0, -1,  0,  0])
```

Comment: Well i gave a simple example to illustrate but what i consider to be a peak/valley is not a nearest neighboring method like you're using, it's a more involved method so i'm not really worried about detecting peaks for this particular part of the problem, more so i am worried about picking out the best peak from a consecutive group of already detected peaks. My method should really be in the form of get_extreme_inds(actual_data, peak_inds, valley_inds) returns peak_inds, valley_inds where a valley index is always in between two peak indexes and visa versa